# How to destroy react cropper method in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, hybrid-mobile-app

I have used react cropper component in reactjs. I made this functionality on popup. Here, i have one button called upload. If i click on the button the popup screen will open. There i have that crop area. There also having the two button like crop and cancel. If i click either crop or cancel button, i can't open same image again. How to resolve this issue?

Here is my code,

```
var React  = require('react')
var Cropper = require('react-cropper').default;

var CropImg = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return {
            open:false,
            src:"",
            cropResult: null,
        }
    },
    onChange:function(e){
        var files, self = this;
        if (e.dataTransfer) {
            files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        } else if (e.target) {
            files = e.target.files;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
            self.setState({
                open:true,
                src: reader.result
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    },
    cropImage:function(){
        if (typeof this.refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas() === 'undefined') {
            return;
        }
        this.setState({
            open:false,
            src:"",
            cropResult: this.refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL(),
        });
    },
    cancelCrop: function() {
        this.setState({
            open:false,
            src:"",
            cropResult:null
        });
    },
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="scroll-content">
                    <input type="file" id="photo" onChange={this.onChange} />
                </div>
                <div className={"profile-popup "+(this.state.open ? "active" : "inactive")}>
                    <div className="crop-area">
                        <Cropper
                            style={{ height: 280, width: '100%' }}
                            aspectRatio={1 / 1}
                            guides={true}
                            src={this.state.src}
                            ref="cropper" />
                        <div className="row-col">
                            <div className="col"><button onClick={this.cropImage}>Crop</button></div>
                            <div className="col"><button onClick={this.cancelCrop}>Cancel</button></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = CropImg;
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` binding.

```
this.cropImage.bind(this)
```